# Increment variable in PowerShell from within if statement within a foreach loop. Seems broken

Tags: powershell, variables, foreach, counting

I have a super easy one here but I cannot figure it out and driving me insane.
I suspect it is some kind of scoping issue of the variable (global, etc.?)

Anyway, here is my code:

```
$i = 0
foreach ($line in Get-Content 'somefile.txt') {

    if ($i = 1) {
        echo "$i Line: $line"
    }
    $i++
    // I even tried $i = $i + 1
}
```

Output is $1 = 1 always. It doesn't seem to count.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `=` is an assignment, to compare use `if ( $i -eq 1){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't clear, but it looks like you're trying to output each line of your text file with the line number prepended.  If so, one way to do it is:

```
Get-Content 'somefile.txt' |
    ForEach-Object {$i = 0}{
        "$i Line: $_"
        $i++
    }
```

Comment: Yeah pretty much what I want to do.
Ideally only show certain lines that match a number.
Still not sure why my code fails to increment a simple variable.

Comment: @GrahamSmart it doesn't fail to increment, you are setting it back to `1` every time the loop runs

Comment: How am i??
I dont see that as the declaration is outside of the loop?

Comment: I hate PS ;)
thanks guys! , boxdog your code worked wonders too !

Answer (score 2):

`$i = 1` *assigns* `1` to `$i`, so the result is always `1`.

You need to use `-eq`: `if ($i -eq 1) ...`

See `Get-Help about_comparison_operators` for more information.